# Creating MSR and Recovery partitions manually

Tags: windows-10

Am I able to manually create Windows 10 MSR and Recovery partitions and force windows to use it?

Comment: You can create an MSR and Recovery partition manually if you know how to do it (and they are missing) in your Windows 10 installation. To force Windows 10 to use the Recovery partition first it must be attached in BCD (boot configuration) and then restart Windows to  Recovery mode.

Comment: reagentc /enable will enable recovery, as for MSR docs say it should be the first created partition, so...